# Exported Function not working with socket.io

Tags: javascript

My exported function which calls an endpoint then is supposed to emit some of the response through to my front-end isnt working, although the same function works when it's in my index.js file within the socket.io function.

My exported function shows no errors, although in my front-end my chat is not showing, where when the function isnt exported it works.

I've consoled the socket.id and the data and it all seems to console fine, but perhaps im missing something with how socket.id emits things?

my function (exported - in external file):

```
exports.getRefundCalculationApiCall = function (itemId, refundCalcEndPoint, domain, orderId, customerName, details, response, socket) {
console.log('ngrokurl 2' + refundCalcEndPoint)
console.log('domain2' + domain)
console.log('orderId2' + orderId)
console.log('itemId2' + itemId)
httpRequest.post(
    `${refundCalcEndPoint}/${domain}/${orderId}`,
    {
        json:
            {
                "line_items": [
                    {
                        "line_item_id": itemId, "quantity": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
    },
    function (error, resp, body) {
        if (!error && resp.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)

            amount1 = body.refund.refund_line_items[0].amount;
            // constructing message to front-end with the refund expense.
            responseToFrontEnd = `Your refund amount would be ${amount1},  Do you accept this and wish to initiate the returns process?`
            console.log( + responseToFrontEnd)
            response = responseToFrontEnd
            data = [details.chatuser, response]
            console.log('data' + data)
            io.of('/main').to(socket.id).emit('response', data);

            console.log('socket.id' + socket.id);
            console.log('are we hitting here in the postRequest get refund calc?');

        }
        else {
            console.log('error' + error)
        }
    }
)
```

}

Calling my function in the my index file - (the calling of the file gives the exact response that i get when the function is called in my index file but the response isnt being emitted):

```
shopifyApiRequest.getRefundCalculationApiCall(itemId, refundCalcEndPoint, domain, orderId, amount1, details, response, socket)
```

The function works fine when I use the whole thing in the same file within the socket function which starts as below:

```
io.of('/main').on('connection', function (socket) {
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because there arent any errors but my expected result is for my message to actually be sent through to the front-end in the same way with the function being exported than if it was included in my index.js file.

Comment: What kind of JS are you using, are you building it with webpack? If no, then exports are not something that are supported by all browsers. The problem could also be, that you did not import `httpRequest`, at least it is not present in your code

Comment: It's just normal JS, the receiving socket function is within Jquery though and the socket function is in a file which is normal JS using node modules, yes the httpRequest and stuff work because the function does work and the response comes back fine it just doesnt send to the front-end?